# Impact Forces on 2 products when dropped together

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Can anyone help me? I need to know the forces exerted on a bag when dropped.

> Example: 2 sacks filled with 12kg product packed on top of each other into a case and then dropped from 1.5m.  What is the force / equivalent weight the bottom bag is subjected too?

Assume sacks are full and there is little space for sacks to move around, sacks land on flat surface. I am guessing this would be like an elephant standing on the bottom sack.

Comment: Are you asking what is the value of the force on the bottom sack when it hits the ground? It seems like question is asking the force when it is in the air.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the force / equivalent weight the bottom bag is subjected too?

There's no single, unequivocal answer here.

It depends on the 'hardness'/'stiffness' of the bags.

For educational purposes we'll assign a Hookean spring constant $k$ to the bags: the higher the $k$, the 'harder/stiffer' the bags are. Conversely the lower the $k$, the 'softer/more elastic' the bags are.

When the bags hit the floor they have a kinetic energy $K$:
 $$K=\frac12 mv^2$$

We'll now assume, mainly for simplicity's sake, that the collision with the floor is elastic and that the floor holds.

In that case, during the contact with the floor, the kinetic energy $K$ by the principle of Energy Conservation is converted to spring potential energy $U$.

$$\frac12 k x^2 =\frac12 mv^2\tag{1}$$

Where $x$ is the displacement (deformation) of the 'spring'. If we take the time derivative $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}$ of both sides  and because $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}=v$ and $\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=a$, we get:

$$2kxv=2mva$$

With Newton's Second:

$$F=ma=kx$$

Which is of course the classic force-displacement formula for Hookean springs. If the total displacement to halt the bags (to $v=0$, so $\Delta v=v-0=v$) is $\Delta x$, then from $(1)$:

$$\Delta x=\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\Delta v$$

And the maximum force $F_{max}$ is:

$$F_{max}=\sqrt{km}\Delta v$$

**So the maximum force is proportional to the velocity change, the mass and the 'stiffness' of the object.**

In the real world $k$ is rarely a constant and the collision with the floor rarely purely elastic.